# No module PyQt5 found when importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have just installed PyQt5 and testing out the code. I already have the designer.exe working fine and I have made my first UI file, but when typing `import pyqt5` it returns this error:

```
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyqt5
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqt5'
```

I tried reinstalling using the Anaconda prompt, oddly enough using the cmd to install PyQt5 returns an error that Python doesn't exist. I am currently using Windows 10 and Python 3.6, I wish I could resolve these issues as it is hindering my progress.

EDIT:
After uninstalling PyQt5 on Anaconda Prompt, I tried reinstalling on cmd and the installation worked fine. I upgraded my pip and other tools, I can now import PyQt5 on IDLE.

Comment: Did you wrote 'pyqt5' instead of 'PyQt5' (regarding to your result) ?

Comment: Try it: `import PyQt5`

Comment: Regardless it it is "pyqt5" or "PyQt5", no it still doesn't work

Comment: Both does not work, I am trying to troubleshoot the problem if it's about my pathing

Comment: @ShunLushiko execute: `python -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: Yeah I've been using that command line to install, no luck.

Comment: @ShunLushiko Have you executed my command?, That a command does not work does not mean that another does not work.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have resolved the issue, thank you for your responses